# What IAM permissions do I need to authenticate with CodeArtifact from Docker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-iam, aws-codeartifact

I have set up CodeArtifact to host my private NuGet packages and mirror public NuGet packages. I can pull these with no problem in my local environment, and GitHub Actions can also log in to pull them to enable CI.

I intend to build my application in a Docker container so I can do some more involved integration testing, and this is where I have hit some issues.

**Docker File excerpt**

```
FROM cakebuild/cake:sdk-6.0 AS build-env
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
ARG AWS_CODEARTIFACT_REPOSITORY
ARG AWS_CODEARTIFACT_DOMAIN
ARG AWS_CODEARTIFACT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
ENV AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
ENV AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
ENV AWS_CODEARTIFACT_REPOSITORY ${AWS_CODEARTIFACT_REPOSITORY}
ENV AWS_CODEARTIFACT_DOMAIN ${AWS_CODEARTIFACT_DOMAIN}
ENV AWS_CODEARTIFACT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER ${AWS_CODEARTIFACT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER}
RUN curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip" && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y unzip && \
    unzip awscliv2.zip && \
    ./aws/install && \
    rm -rf awscliv2.zip aws

WORKDIR /source

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ./src/Application/*.csproj ./Application/
COPY ./src/Infrastructure/*.csproj ./Infrastructure/
COPY ./src/ProfileAPI/*.csproj ./ProfileAPI/

RUN aws configure set default.region eu-west-2 && \
    aws configure set aws_access_key_id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID && \
    aws configure set aws_secret_access_key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY && \
    aws configure set output json
RUN aws codeartifact login --tool dotnet --repository $AWS_CODEARTIFACT_REPOSITORY --domain $AWS_CODEARTIFACT_DOMAIN --domain-owner $AWS_CODEARTIFACT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
```

If I try and build this with the relevant arguments like so.

```
docker build -t profile-api --build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxxxxx --build-arg AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=xxxxx --build-arg AWS_CODEARTIFACT_REPOSITORY=xxxxx --build-arg AWS_CODEARTIFACT_DOMAIN=xxxx --build-arg AWS_CODEARTIFACT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER=xxxx .
```

Then it complains.

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: User: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxx:user/PackageRead is not authorized to perform: codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken on resource: arn:aws:codeartifact:eu-west-2:xxxxx:domain/xxxxxbecause no resource-based policy allows the 
codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken action
```

I have added that permission to the user and it still complains:-

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codeartifact:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:GetServiceBearerToken",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "sts:AWSServiceName": "codeartifact.amazonaws.com"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible reason for `AccessDeniedException` on `codeartifact:GetAuthorizationToken` could be incorrect Account ID:

Once check the account ID passed (or you can remove the account id while authenticating) for the build variable `AWS_CODEARTIFACT_ACCOUNT_NUMBER`

Other than this there is no possibility of another issue as of my knowledge.

Comment: I feel stupid now. Thank you.